# How to decide whether following series is convergent: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2\left( 2/3\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to decide whether the following series is convergent or otherwise: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2\left( 2/3\right)^n$?

One way to do is to use **root test**, I am wondering if other ways are possible.

Comment: It is fairly easy to sum the first $m$ terms explicitly. Then you can see both the limit and the amount by which the sum of the first $m$ terms differs from it.

Comment: But if you simply want to prove convergence as easily as possible, the ratio test looks the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

One can use the ratio test, as the limit of the ratio of successive terms is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{3} \left(1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \frac{2}{3} < 1 \textrm{.}$$

Answer (score 2):

As an **extension** to the question, one may evaluate the sum exactly (after proving that it converges). Note that for $|x| < 1$,

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$$
$$x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty nx^{n}$$
$$x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n^2x^{n}$$
$$\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3} = 0^2x^0 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^2x^{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^2x^{n}$$

Substituting $x = \frac{2}{3}$, we have the required sum:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n} = 30$$

Answer (score 1):

ratio test:

$$
\dfrac{(n+1)^2 2^{n+1} 3^{n}}{n^22^n 3^{n+1}} = \dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}
$$

the limit of which is...

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=n^2(2/3)^n$. Now perform comparison test i.e. $$\limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim((1+1/n)^2)\frac23 =\frac23<1$$
So the series will converge.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the ratio test. $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{2}2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^{2}2^{n}}{3^{n}}}=\frac{(n+1)^{2}2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}\frac{3^{n}}{n^{2}2^{n}}=\frac{2}{3}\frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n^{2}}=\frac{2}{3}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)$$ Now you can take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ on the RHS equation and we'll see it converge to $\frac{2}{3}$. Since $|\frac{2}{3}|<1$ we know that the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2(\frac{2}{3})^n}=\frac{2}{3}<1.$ This shows that the series will converge.